# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory (In Node.Js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create Text file named : "message.txt" but I always get this error :

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'message.txt'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:448:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1210:35)
    at Server.http.createServer (C:\Users\lasqu\Documents\Programming\NodeJS\app.js:15:15)
    at Server.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:680:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:113:17)
```

I've tried everything, but I still have no solution for this.

Here's my Javascript code :

```
const http = require('http');
const fileS = require('fs');


const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {
    const url = req.url;
    const method = req.method;

    if (url === "/")
    {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.write('<html>');
        res.write('<body><form action="/send" method="POST"><input type="text" name="send"><button type="sumbit">SEND</button></form></body>');
        res.write('</html>');
        fileS.writeFileSync('message.txt', "DUMMY", 'utf8');
        res.statusCode = 302;
        res.setHeader('Location', '/');
        return  res.end();
    }
    if (url === "/send" && method === 'POST')
    {

        return res.end();
    }

    // process.exit();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.write('<html>');
    res.write('<body><h1>SEND NUDES</h1></body>');
    res.write('</html>');
});

server.listen(100);
```

Comment: What is your node version? Did you try to remove `'utf8'`? It is the default value, so it is worthless and maybe it unsets the default flag which should create the file if unexisting?

Comment: I'm using node v11.12.0, I've removed the `'utf8'` it does not resolve the error. @s

Comment: Here is the right syntax node 11 : fs.writeSync(fd, string[, position[, encoding]]) https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writesync_fd_string_position_encoding, set 0 for position

Comment: it's working here

Comment: @guijob same on my computer. @Christopher, I don't know what's going wrong but that's not normal... Are you sure you actually call the official `fs` without any middleware or anything? Maybe something about permissions in your current working directory?

Comment: @sjahan I think that there is something wrong with the permission on my computer, and yes i am using the official ```fs``` without middleware or what so ever.

Comment: @sjahan I know what is the culprit, it was my antivirus, it doesn't allow any applications to modify anyfiles on my private folders, the solutions is to use other directory on my storage. thanks for your help

Comment: @ChristopherLasquite glad you solved it ;)